Is 형 [hyeong] related to Cantonese 兄 hing1 [hɪŋ]?
I heard the word for what seems to be older brother: 형 [hyeong], in a brand new, newly released, second season of a very popular tv show yesterday.
I do not know very much Korean but it sounded very similar to Cantonese 兄 hing1 [hɪŋ].
Anecdotally, I have heard from non-Chinese speaking Koreans that Cantonese is easier to pick words out of than Mandarin due to closer proximity to Korean. I am not sure if this is really the case or not though.
Is it possible that there is any connection?

Yes. 형 "older brother" has hanja spelling 兄, and comes from Middle Chinese 兄, which in Zhengzhang
Shangfang's reconstruction was /hˠwiæŋ/.
